# C# SQL database access from another PC

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, network-programming, connection-string

I am using C#, .NET Framework 4.5.2 and SQL Server 2014 Express edition (v12.0.2000).  My requirement is to access this software from another PC means client system. Software is working fine in server PC not accessible in client PC.

**Working until now**

I followed the following two Microsoft official documents to make the database accessible on another PC:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-1-connecting-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer?view=sql-server-ver15

To connect two PCs I followed [this tutorial](https://afteracademy.com/blog/can-you-connect-two-computers-for-file-sharing-without-using-a-hub-or-router).

**Result so far**

I am able to access software in the network directory. I can run the `.exe` file of software on the client's PC. I can access the SQL Server in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio on the client PC.

**Can't do so far**

The only thing that I can't do till now is my software on the client's PC is not able to access the database. It shows an error

> Login failed for user

**Connection string**

I thought it should be a connection string error. I tried three different connection strings, let me write all here:

1. `Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=dbposrpc;trusted_connection=true;`
2. `Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbposrpc;User ID=sa;Password=12345678;`
3. `Data Source=tcp:DESKTOP-0DCQGE3,49172;Initial Catalog=dbposrpc;User ID=sa;Password=12345678;`

`SQLEXPRESS` is the SQL Server instance name, `DESKTOP-0DCQGE3` is the server PC name, `49172` is the TCP port that I selected.

Comment: If the error is login failed, I'm quite sure that's what it means. I don't think trusted connection can work because you don't have a domain with a common user. Do you have mixed mode enabled (=also SQL Server users can login)? Does SA work with the other pc when trusted connection is not used?

Comment: _49172 is the TCP port that I selected_ What exactly does that mean? Did you set that instance to use this specific port or is that the port that the instance dynamically chooses when it starts? Typically you do not set a fixed port number and allow the instance to dynamically choose it at startup. This means that the sql browser must be running and working. And in the future, post the complete error message - all of it including the code, severity, etc.

Comment: The login failed error means you have successfully reached the SQL instance but authentication failed or the database cannot be accessed. The SQL Server error log will have more info on the error.

Comment: @JamesZ yes mixed mode is enabled

Comment: @SMor I tried to post each and everything but still missed the stuff that you mentioned, for next time I will keep your suggestions in mind. I am using 49172 port as a static port specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved! All the steps I followed are perfect. You can say that if you want to connect to the client's PC using an ethernet connection. Follow the steps in question step by step. Focus on the connection string. Use the connection string of number 3. Let me write it again for clarification.

```
Data Source=tcp:DESKTOP-0DCQGE3,49172;Initial Catalog=dbposrpc;User ID=sa;Password=12345678;
```

Here `SQLEXPRESS` is the SQL Server instance name, `DESKTOP-0DCQGE3` is the server PC name, `49172` is the TCP port that I selected as static.

**How I resolved the issue?**

I just cleared the solution, restarted the project again and everything worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing a software from remote PC(Client's PC) you need to add `inbound rules` in `Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security` for this port the software is hosted on, then you also need to forward the port from your server PC.

Comment: inbound rules added already, also mentioned in my question with the link that I followed.

Comment: Also ```Port forwarding``` should be done

Comment: Did you forward the port from your server pc network? You can check it out here https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-port-forward-4163829

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @SYEDNAWAZPRINCE I understood your point. Your answer is not according to my question. Kindly check the article that I shared. I didn't communicate with two PCs via the router, I connected them directly via ethernet without involving the router. In that case, port forwarding is not needed. I hope I clarified my point. I suggest you look at the links that I discussed in my question. Thanks for your time